# Generate dependent combinations from array

Tags: python

I would like to generate combinations out of an array (always 4 elements):

```
arr = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

I'm currently using:

```
itertools.combinations(arr, 2)
```

This returns me pairs:

```
 ("1","2"),("1","3"),("1","4"),("2","3"),("2","4"),("3","4")
```

What i'd like to do is to generate dependent combinations only:

```
 [("1","2"),("3","4")]
 [("1","3"),("2","4")]
 [("1","4"),("2","3")]
```

Meaning that if i have combination out of strings `"1"` and `"2"` only other combination left is `"3"` and `"4"`. My current solution just uses `itertools` and due to that each calculation is done twice (once for `"1","2"` pair with `"3","4"` (so pair `"3","4"` in this case is calculated separately; iterating over the `arr` again leaving out `"1"` and `"2"`) and another time `"3","4"` pair with `"1","2"`).

I believe there should be more elegant way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is always of 4 elements (as you stated), you can easily construct all the options:

```
arr = ["1","2","3","4"]
for i in range(1,4):
    print([arr[0], arr[i]], arr[1:i] + arr[i+1:])

#output: 
['1', '2'] ['3', '4']
['1', '3'] ['2', '4']
['1', '4'] ['2', '3']
```

Answer (score 3):

For fun, here's a solution which will work for any number of even elements, assuming you want to split into two even groups per dependent combination:

```
from itertools import combinations

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
group_size = len(arr) // 2

tuples = list(combinations(arr, group_size))
dependent_combinations = [
  [tuples[i], tuples[-i-1]]
  for i in range(len(tuples) // 2)
]
print(dependent_combinations)
```

Output:

```
[
    [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)],
    [(1, 2, 4), (3, 5, 6)],
    [(1, 2, 5), (3, 4, 6)],
    [(1, 2, 6), (3, 4, 5)],
    [(1, 3, 4), (2, 5, 6)],
    [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)],
    [(1, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5)],
    [(1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 6)],
    [(1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5)],
    [(1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4)]
]
```